# How to create a pointer to store any function with any number of arguments?

Tags: c++, windows, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to put together an Event system for my engine. I had the idea of storing pointer to the function I want the Event to execute inside the Event struct, but so far I was unsucessfull.
I'm completely new to passing functions through arguments to other functions.

I managed to put together this:

```
decltype(auto) _funcExec(Function&& func, Args&&...args)
{
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But that only allows me to execute another function through the _funcExec function..
I need to somehow make a type out of this: `(Function&& func, Args&&...args)` so I can make a pointer member of my Event struct and store the pointer to the function I want the Event struct to execute..

And the concept is something like this:

```
struct sEvent {
    std::vector<sEventArg> arg;
    std::function<void()> _storedFunc;
    bool _funcStored = false;

    template <class Function, class ... Args>
    bool storeFunc(Function&& func, Args&&...args)
    {
        if( _funcStored ) return false;

        _storedFunc = std::forward<Function>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        _funcStored = true;
        return true;
    }
    auto executeFunc( void )
    {
        if( !_funcStored ) return error();
        return _storedFunc(arg[0].get_int32(), arg[1].get_float); // no instance matches the argument list
    }
};
```

Event is created, stored in a queue and when the time comes it executes the function that was passed to it at creation time. Many events can be created with different functions to execute. The goal is not to write two more functions(setter for event, and event exec) for every function in the engine I want to be executable through the Event system..

I hope I explained it comprehensively.

So I have two questions..

1. Is that even possible?
   and if yes
2. HOW? :D

Thank you.

Ahaaahaha.. the answer was there all along! This should work..

```
struct sEvent {
    std::function<void()> _storedFunc;
    template <typename Function, typename ...Args>
    bool storeFunc( Function&& func, Args&&...args )
    {
        _storedFunc = std::function<void()>{ [=]() { func( args... ); } };
        return true;
    }
    auto _execFunc( void )
    {
        return _storedFunc();
    }
};
```

Thank you all and especially to @Ted Lyngmo and @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Edit: So after two days playing with it I was not able to feed this any functions, with arguments, without args, void, auto, nothing :(

Comment: You could use a `std::function<void()>` and store a lambda that calls any function inside.

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Do you want to execute the events function multiple times in the future, each time with a different set of arguments, or just once, with a fixed set of args?

Comment: You are running into two fundamental C++ concepts: 1) The type of all objects must be known at compile time, and 2) Function parameters are a part of its type definition, for the function and any pointer to it. Combine this in a blender and you reach the following conclusion: it is not possible to define a pointer type in C++ to a function that has some unspecified arguments, that are determined at runtime. C++ simply doesn't work this way, fundamentally.

Comment: @TooTone Multiple times I guess, concept is that: Event is created, stored in a queue and when the time comes it executes the function that was passed to it at creation time. Many events can be created with different functions to execute. The goal is not to write two more functions(setter for event, and event exec) for every function in the engine I want to be executable through the Event system.. If it makes sense :)

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Maybe I explained it badly.. I need to store only the pointer to the function, I store the actual parameter values in a vector. I updated the original question with a concept eplanation.

Comment: odd. this is second such question in last two days (third if counting ru.stachoverflow, there was a carbon copy of such). Are people busy doing something cool?

Comment: @Vandover as I said before in response to such, use callback + message pattern. Make all functions having same type argument which somehow contain or refers to stored data.

Comment: @Swift Yep, something similar is my backup, but I'd like to be able to execute any function inside the object structure that makes my engine through the Event system, and to do it somewhat elegantly if possible 8)

Comment: your event system doesn't have a proxy type for single event(kind of like in Qt)? And solution in that case would be similar to your `make_function` anyway, only storing a proxy

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It has, that is the Event struct, the system is actually in EventQueue class and Events in it are stored in a std::queue.. a deque actually. The `make_function` approach is great and should probably work for what I intend, but I'm not able to create anything to store the function inside the Event struct

Comment: A pointer is not some anonymous entity, stripped of all attributes. There is no such thing in C++ as a "pointer to some function with unspecified parameters". Function parameters are part of the function type. The type of a pointer to a function includes the function type, i.e. its parameters. That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, that was the main problem I was asking how to overcome.. And it seems the answer was as usual: with magic. :) So far it seems it could work with the `std::function<void()>` and storing the lambda (I have no idea yet what that even means :D need to read about it) but it compiles, need to yet test if it really works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can turn function + arguments into a `std::function<void()>`. You left out many details, using the code you did provide, you can turn it into the following to store the `std::function`s somewhere:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename Function, typename ...Args>
auto make_function(Function&& func, Args&&...args)
{
    return std::function<void()>{
        [=](){ func(args...); }
    };
}

void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n" ;}
void bar(int x) { std::cout << "bar" << x << "\n"; }

int main() {
    auto f = make_function(foo);
    f();
    auto g = make_function(bar,42);
    g();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEq37W7hf)

Comment: Ahh, I see.. This looks promising, thank you. Gonna try it out.

Comment: This really helped a lot to steer me towards a great solution. Thank You!

Comment: Reinventing the wheel. `std:: function<void> g = std::bind_front(bar, 42);` in C++26, it can be `std::bind_front<bar>(42);`